# WatchKit: Animation Images stored in App Group

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, animation, watchkit

I'm using App Groups to store an `NSData` of JPEG images created with `UIImageJPEGRepresentation()`. Now I want to use the images data contained in that array as animation frames for a `WKInterfaceImage` instance.

I've successfully archived my `NSData` of JPEG images from my App Group using `NSKeyedUnarchiver`, and now I'm caching the images needed to convey the animation.

```
    var frames = ...
    for (index, frame) in enumerate(frames) {
        WKInterfaceDevice().addCachedImageWithData(frame, name: "frame" + String(index))
    }

    animationImage.setImageNamed("frame")
    animationImage.startAnimating()
```

Unfortunately this code does not seem to work; when I open the corrisponding `WKInterfaceController`, I just see a loading screen for 2/3 minutes than a "Unable to find image named "frame" on Watch
" message on the console. I cannot use Images.xcassets folder to store the animation frames since they are dynamically generated by the app.

Does anybody know how to solve this problem?

Answer (score 1):

The trick to getting this to work is to combine all of your UIImages into a single UIImage object and send that to the device. See below.

```
import WatchKit
import Foundation

class InterfaceController: WKInterfaceController {
    @IBOutlet weak var imageView: WKInterfaceImage!

    override func awakeWithContext(context: AnyObject?) {
        super.awakeWithContext(context)

        var imageArray : NSMutableArray = [];
        for ( var index = 0; index < 10; ++index ) {
            var imageName = "frame" + String(index) 
            var image = UIImage(named:imageName);
            if ( image != nil ) {
                imageArray.addObject(image!)
            }
        }
        var combinedImage = UIImage.animatedImageWithImages(imageArray, duration:1); 
        WKInterfaceDevice().addCachedImage(combinedImage, name: "frame");
    }

    override func willActivate() {
        super.willActivate()
        self.imageView.setImageNamed("frame")
        self.imageView.startAnimating()
    }

    override func didDeactivate() {
        super.didDeactivate()
        self.imageView.stopAnimating()
    }
}
```

Comment: It worked but it is very, very slow in the simulator. Even with 30 different frames, the loading times are crazy.

Comment: I'm not sure if you'll ever get the performance you want. Make sure the images are as small as possible - maybe JPEGs instead of PNGs and maybe 1x resolution instead of 2x. Perhaps cut the number images from 30 to 15.

Comment: Documentation says that animated images support up to 1024 frames. I'm using about 200 very small images. If I put them in the Images.xcassets folder everything gets loaded immediately. There must be a way of doing that...

Answer (score 1):

This definitely does work and your approach is sound. The problem is that you cannot actually load the cached images until they've been transferred to the Watch. This is a bit of a tricky situation. Long story short, you want to push those dynamic images to Watch way before you need to add them to an interface element to be displayed.

A simple demonstration of this could be to change up your code to the following:

```
let data = NSData() // obviously make this an image
WKInterfaceDevice().addCachedImageWithData(data, name: "example_image")

dispatch_after(dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, Int64(4.0 * Float(NSEC_PER_SEC))), dispatch_get_main_queue()) { [weak self] in
    if let strongSelf = self {
        strongSelf.animationImage.setImageNamed("example_image")
    }
}
```

> Four seconds might not be enough time to transfer the image. You'll have to play with that value.

The iOS Simulator has really odd behavior for the transfer. It blocks the main thread of the Watch App while the transfer is in progress. Hopefully this doesn't actually occur on the main thread of the device.

Comment: That's a pain! Do you have knowledge of the mean transfer time for an image of 50-100KB?

Comment: I do not. You'll have to use trial and error to figure it out on an actual device.